# All my custom date-range components ngModel are synchronized in ngFor

Tags: angular

I've create a `date-range` input component base on *Angular Material DatePicker* ([see docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)).

```
<date-range *ngFor="let range of ranges; let i = index;" [(ngModel)]="ranges[i].data" [required]="true" name="range-{{i}}"></date-range>
```

If I pick a date in one of the `date-range` all of them are set to that date.
I've seen some question & answers suggesting to use the `ranges[index]` not the `range` template var and I'm already doin so, seen others suggesting to bind the index with the name and also I'm doing so.

###### date-range.component.html

```html
<div class="{{classes}}">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
        <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker" [disabled]="disabled">
            <input matStartDate formControlName="start" [placeholder]="startPlaceholder || 'jj/mm/aaaa'" [required]="startRequired || required" [readonly]="startReadonly || readonly" [disabled]="startDisabled || disabled" (dateChange)="log('testing: '+value); writeValue({start: $event.value, end: null})">
            <input matEndDate formControlName="end" [placeholder]="endPlaceholder || 'jj/mm/aaaa'" [required]="endRequired || required" [readonly]="endReadonly || readonly" [disabled]="endDisabled || disabled" (dateChange)="writeValue({start: value.start, end: $event.value})">
        </mat-date-range-input>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

        <mat-hint *ngIf="hint" class="text-sm text-muted">{{hint}}</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

###### date-range.component.ts

```
type Data = {
  start: Date|null,
  end: Date|null
}

@Component({
  selector: 'date-range',
  templateUrl: './date-range.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../form-field.component.css'],
  providers: [MakeProvider(DateRangeComponent)]
})
export class DateRangeComponent extends AbstractValueAccessor {

  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
    end: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
  });

  @Input()
  label:string="";
  /* ... */

  override _value:any = {
    start: null,
    end: null
  }

  override get value() {
    return this._value || {
      start: null,
      end: null
    };
  }

  @Input()
  override set value(v: any) {
    if (!v) {
      v = {
        start: null,
        end: null
      }
    }
    let change = false;
    if (!this.areEqual(v.start, this.value.start)) {
      this.range.controls.start.setValue(v.start);
      change = true;
    }
    if (!this.areEqual(v.end, this.value.end)) {
      this.range.controls.end.setValue(v.end);
      change = true;
    }      
    if (change){
      this._value = v;
      this.onChange(v);
    }
  }

  override writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (!value)
      return;
    this.range.controls.start.setValue(value.start);
    this.range.controls.end.setValue(value.end);
    super.writeValue(value)
  }

  areEqual(v1:any, v2:any):boolean {
    if (!v1)
      return !v2;
    if (!v2)
      return !v1;

    if (v1 instanceof Date && v2 instanceof Date) {
      if (isNaN(v1.valueOf()) || isNaN(v2.valueOf()))
        return false;

      v1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      v2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      return v1.getTime() === v2.getTime();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

value-accessor.ts

```
export abstract class AbstractValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    _value: any = '';
    get value(): any { return this._value; };
    set value(v: any) {
      if (v !== this._value) {
        this._value = v;
        this.onChange(v);
      }
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
      this._value = value;
      this.onChange(value);
    }

    onChange = (_:any) => {};
    onTouched = () => {};
    registerOnChange(fn: (_:any) => void):void { this.onChange = fn; }
    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void):void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}

export function MakeProvider(type : any){
  return {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => type),
    multi: true
  };
}
```

> NOTE: I spent about 2 weeks debugging this use case, please if you see anything not adding up feel free to mention

preview at [stackblitz](https://angular-spans4.stackblitz.io)

Comment: create a stackblitz example.

Comment: here you go [stackblitz](https://angular-spans4.stackblitz.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use fill it uses the same object to all the indices

```js
//Case 1
const arr = Array(3).fill({start:1,end:2});
console.log(arr); // [{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}]
arr[0].end = 3; // update arr[0].end -> 3 
// **(since it is the same object by reference in all indices value is updated)
console.log(arr);// [{1,3},{1,3},{1,3}]
```

What you should be doing is

```
// Case 2
const arr = Array(3).fill(undefined).map(v => ({start:1,end:2}));
console.log(arr); // [{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}]
arr[0].end = 3; // update arr[0].end -> 3 
// **(since it is not the same object by reference only first object is updated)
console.log(arr);// [{1,3},{1,2},{1,2}]
```

```js
// Line 43 app.component.ts
// ?? NOTE CHANGE MADE HERE ------------------------->>>>>
this.ranges = Array(value).fill(undefined).map(i => ({
  start: null,
  end: null,
}));
```

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpqyp5?file=src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fforms%2Fdate-range%2Fdate-range.component.ts,src%2Fforms%2Fdate-range%2Fdate-range.component.html,src%2Fapp.component.ts)